# How do I update META tags for a ruby / react.js?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, reactjs

I have a news website where the DOM is rendered in react.js and the backend is designed in Ruby on Rails. My problem is that because the DOM is virtual, facebook is unable to [scrape](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) the information and thus the "facebook share" does not load up the images or the page title. Each time the user visits a new page on my site, only a portion of the page is reloaded and not the whole page (react.js).

My question: How do I update the meta tags when only a portion of the page is reloaded so that Facebook can scrape it properly if somebody decides to share my url?

I'm not sure if the best way to do it is by rebuilding the way the main front pages are built in ruby, or by using some simpler reactjs or jquery solution.

---

Here's what I've tried (without success). To explain - when the content section and header section refresh, I want the shared image to be the header image and the shared title to be the content header title. This doesn't work:

```
    $("meta[property='og:image']").attr($('#header_photo').css('background-image'));

  if($('#discuss_header_question').length) { 
    $("meta[property='og:title']").html($('#header_content_title'));
    } else {
      $("meta[property='og:title']").html("mywebsite.com generic title.");
    }
```

Comment: You can't use javascript to do this because Facebook is only scraping the HTML. It doesn't run any javascript in the returned HTML.

Comment: For each individual piece of content you want to share, you need an individual URL as well, and that URL has to deliver HTML code containing the relevant Open Graph meta tags when requested from your server.

Comment: So is there no way to update the opengraph attributes in the meta tags via React.js? that seems odd, since Facebook is the one that created React.js ...

Comment: If you run React.js on the server you can.

Comment: CBroe - yes, each page has its own url. e.g. for topic 1, the url is www.mysite.com/#discuss/1 
@WizKid - how can I do that? could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: I think you can run node.js on the server and do it

Comment: This is the reason I send a django template from the server with meta tags populated then use react to build the dom from there.  SEO and meta tags are a big deal.

Comment: You can use either  server side rendering or a service like https://prerender.io/